# How to write W3C compliant multi-level bullet points in HTML?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, html-lists

Is it possible to write W3C compliant multi-level bullet points (unordered list) in HTML?

Nested ul can be used, but is not W3C compliant.

```
 <ul>
     <li>myItem 1</li>
     <li>myItem 2</li>
     <ul>
        <li>myItem 2a</li>
     </ul>
     <li>myItem 3</li>
     <li>myItem 4</li>
 </ul>
```

- myItem 1
- myItem 2
  - myItem 2a
- myItem 3
- myItem 4

In Visual Studio, the above code gives the warning: **Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'ul' cannot be nested within element 'ul'**

Comment: What does the validator complain about when you tried it? Please post sample HTML and exact validation output.

Comment: Have you tried putting an `<ul>` inside a `<li>` and seeing what the validator says?

Comment: You should be able to naturally. If not, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: As this thread bore out, that's not the case, Ben.  Here is a similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235257/how-can-i-produce-an-nested-list-in-xhtml-strict-without-giving-the-nested-lists

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The only valid child of either a `ul` or `ol` is an `li` element; an `li` can, however, contain a `ul` (or `ol`). To achieve your aim:

```html
<ul>
  <li>myItem 1</li>
  <li>myItem 2</li>
  <li style="list-style-type:none">
    <ul>
      <li>myItem 2a</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>myItem 3</li>
  <li>myItem 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ...if someone could edit my code block as code, it'd be appreciated (I don't know if it's the weirdness of iPhone editing, or my own misuse that's screwing it up, despite repeated attempts).

Comment: I haven't got enough points to edit your answer :-( Your code creates an unwanted bullet point. How can I get rid of that? Thanks.

Comment: WTF? The last `<ul>` broke the entire formatting until I removed all the spaces. Never seen that before. Must have been some evil Apple trickery :)

Comment: Thanks @Pekka, I'm glad it wasn't just me that was confused, I had started to worry =)

Comment: This is not the answer because it creates an unwanted bullet (before the nested <ul>).

Comment: It's the only **valid (x)html** solution. The extra bullet should be dealt with via css. I'd suggest asking a separate question for help with that problem.

Comment: Actually all you have to do is put the nested UL in the 2nd li rather than creating a blank one. Then you won't get the unwanted bullet

Answer (score 21):

Complementing David Thomas answer, this would remove the unwanted bullet:

```html
<ul>
    <li>myItem 1</li>
    <li>myItem 2        
        <ul>
            <li>myItem 2a</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>myItem 3</li>
    <li>myItem 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: NB: it requires at least one `li` element in parent `ul`

Comment: This is, in fact, the correct answer. The point is that `muItem 2a` is indented because it is nested _inside_ `myItem 2`, so the `ul` should be nested _inside_ its `li`

Comment: It worked perfectly well for me, and it is simpler that David Thomas solution. Thanks to Marlon

Comment: Best and simplest answer.